# Program will print largest number and smallest number

Tags: java

I have some trouble when I try to code a program.

```
double max = 0, min = 0;
int i;
double array[] = new double[10];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Give the " + (i + 1) + " number");
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The Max is :" + max);
System.out.println("The Min is :" + min);
```

When I type 10 numbers that include one largest number and one smallest number,
the result is 
The Max is : largest number
The Min is : 0.0

Always the Smallest I get the 0.0 whatever I type. No 2 I will type, No 4 I will type as a smallest number (always on separate launch), every time I get 0.0.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are entering positive numbers only? In that case, how do you expect `array[i] < min` _ever_ to be true, considering that you initialized `min` as `0` …? This needs to be done exactly the other way around as for the maximum - you need to start with a “high enough” value for min, something like `min = 9999`

Comment: Also, your max and min are initialized as 0, this never changes so when you evaluate the array against them you are always going to be evaluating the min and max against 0, thats why you get 0.0

Comment: @MasterYoda    I Know that is not an algorithm. I Added by mistake the tag.

Comment: @CBroe I will try now!  EDIT: Both max and min are reading the 1st Number. Even type 2 or something else, It will show me 2.0 or something else in result.

Comment: Inicialize max to `Double.MIN_VALUE` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and min to `Double.MAX_VALUE` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE), whatever comes will be greater in max case and will be less in min case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Initializing max and min before entering number into the array , when tring to find the max and the min , first enter the numbers to the array then compare them with the array[0].
second thing is that you dont need to for loops to check whether you need to change max or min , you can do it in one for loop . 
try this :

```
    double array[] = new double[10];
    int i;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Give the " + (i + 1) + " number");
        array[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    double max = array[0], min = array[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];

        }

        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The Max is :" + max);
    System.out.println("The Min is :" + min);
```

Comment: That is what I want! Thanks a lot. Any further question, I will ask again

Answer (score 3):

Your initial value for minimum is zero, and I assume your data has nothing that is less than zero.

Try setting your `min` initial value to Double.MAX_VALUE

Comment: `Double.MAX_VALUE` is a better idea than my 9999 of course :-)

Comment: Give the 1 number
2
Give the 2 number
3
Give the 3 number
4
Give the 4 number
5
Give the 5 number
6
Give the 6 number
7
Give the 7 number
8
Give the 8 number
9
Give the 9 number
11
Give the 10 number
12
The Μax is :2.0
The Μin is :2.0

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are not proper. You are ending the max loop before the SYSOUT.

```
    double max = 0, min = 0;
    int i;

    double array[] = new double[10] ;    
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Give the " + (i+1) + " number") ;
        array[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }            
        max = array[0];
        min = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
            }

            }

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                
                if (array[i] < min) {
                    min = array[i];
                }
            }       

        System.out.println("The Max is :" + max);
        System.out.println("The Min is :" + min);
```

Run this. It will give the proper result.

Comment: The Max is :0.0
The Min is :0.0
I want to type 10 numbers that I want and then the program will find the largest number and the smallest one.

Comment: This works for that also. Try running it in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**Two simple corrections:**

1. You just have to **set initialized** min and max to some values in array. (**e.g. array[0]** for your problem)
2. there is  no need to 3 for loops to find the min and max, **just use one**.

see below code:

```
int i;
double array[] = new double[10] ;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;

System.out.println("Give the " + (1) + " number") ;
array[0] = input.nextDouble();

double max = array[0], min = array[0];

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Give the " + (i+1) + " number") ;
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();

    if(array[i] > max)
        max = array[i] ;

    if (array[i] < min)
        min = array[i];
}

System.out.println("The Max is :" + max);
System.out.println("The Min is :" + min);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is already answered. Is the same as answered now with less code. :)